# jquery date picker locale setting not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

the documentation seems simple enough, but in practice, this feature is not working!

I need the date to be in dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
$(function() {
    $("#txt_date").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
});
```

Can you help?

Currently the date is outputted as mm/dd/yyyy.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create language specific files if you need to use the Localization.

See this post http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization

If you only need one date format, dd/mm/yyyy, just use this

```
$( "#txt_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: Cheers Marko, 

Tha works, just one thing, the output needs yo be

dd/mm/yy

and the year was repeating twice in your solution. (just for ref)

Many thanks